# no rviz on hydro medusa

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ubuntu 13.04 and ROS Hydro medusa. When i try this command

```
rosdep install rviz
```

I'm get an error

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource rviz
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

I already install all package for ros-hydro*.

So how could i install rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61963/no-rviz-on-hydro-medusa/) by [andri](https://answers.ros.org/users/4465/andri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Rviz** has not yet been released for Hydro, which is still in alpha testing.

You can try building the [groovy-devel](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz) branch from source. There may be problems, but feel free to ask another (separate) question if it does not work.

I believe **rviz** is being replaced by **rqt_rviz**, which *has* been released to Hydro, but I don't see any Ubunutu binary packages for it, yet. There is a **ros-hydro-rqt-rviz** source package for Raring.

**UPDATE**: Several people pointed out that **rqt_rviz** does *not* replace **rviz**, it just provides an **rqt** wrapper. So, you either need to wait for **ros-hydro-rviz** or build it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-05-02**:
I've started the release process for rviz in hydro, so it should be there soon. It's still going to be rviz. rqt_rviz wraps rviz as an rqt plugin.

**Comment by [andri](https://answers.ros.org/users/4465/andri/) on 2013-05-02**:
Ok...thank you for the answer. I'll try it

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-02**:
@dgossow is right: `rqt_rviz` does NOT intend to replace `rviz`; it depends on `rviz`. That's why it's failing to build.